# How to create multiple rows for every workingday between an start and end date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I would like te create a row for every workable day between my startdate and enddate. So that the amount of production is divided over the real weeks and not only the startweek.

what i have now:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
      PH.ProdHeaderOrdNr,
      PH.ProdstatusCode,
      PH.partcode,
      PH.description,
      PBOM.subpartcode,
      PBOM.description as N'Description subpart',
      PBOO.qty,
      PBOO.producedqty,
      PBOO.machcycletime,
      PBOO.qty-PBOO.producedqty as N'to produce',
      case when(PBOO.qty-PBOO.producedqty)*(1+(convert(decimal(4,2),PBOM.waste)/100))<=0 
           then 0 
           else (PBOO.qty-PBOO.producedqty)*(1+(convert(decimal(4,2),PBOM.waste)/100)) 
           end as N'amount subpart needed',
      (DATEDIFF(dd, PBOO.startdate, PBOO.enddate) + 1)
              -(DATEDIFF(wk, PBOO.startdate, PBOO.enddate) * 2)
              -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, PBOO.startdate) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
              -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, PBOO.enddate) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
              As NoOfWeekDays,
      case when PBOO.machcycletime *((PBOO.qty-PBOO.producedqty)/PBOO.qty)/3600<=0 
           then 0 
           else  Round(PBOO.machcycletime *((PBOO.qty-PBOO.producedqty)/PBOO.qty)/3600,2) 
           end as N'hours remaining',
      PBOO.startdate,
      PBOO.enddate,
      datepart(year,PBOO.startdate) as N'Year',
      datepart(isoww,PBOO.startdate) as N'Week'

FROM
         dbo.T_ProductionHeader  AS PH,
         dbo.T_ProdBillofMat as PBOM,
         dbo.T_Part as P,
         dbo.T_ProdBillOfOper as PBOO,
         dbo.T_MachGrp as M

Where
    PH.ProdHeaderDossierCode = PBOM.ProdHeaderDossierCode    AND
    PH.ProdHeaderDossierCode = PBOO.ProdHeaderDossierCode AND
    PBOO.MachGrpCode = M.MachGrpCode AND
    M.DeptCode = '0720' and
    PH.ProdStatusCode BETWEEN 30 and 40 AND
    PBOM.LineNr = '10' and
    left(PH.partcode,1) in ('P', 'H')and
    PBOO.finishedInd = 0
```

Resulting in:

[image: resulting table with 1 row per production order]

I would like to get the next result:

n amount of rows where N equals amount of workdays from start to enddate
and the values of the following columns spread out over those working days

- "to produce"
- "amount subpart needed"
- " hours remaining"

Added columns

- "running date" (date of workday)
- "running year" (Year of running date)
- "running week" (isoweek of running date)

I Removed the "NoOfWeekDays" column

[image: resulting table with N amount of rows per production order]

I have tried to create a CTE but can't get it to work.

---

Based on the answer of KumarHarsh:

i get the following result:
[result based on KumarHarsh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILBCW.png)

and this is my current sql-code:

```
With CTE As
(
 Select PH.ProdHeaderOrdNr,
      PH.ProdstatusCode,
      PH.partcode,
      PH.description,
      PBOM.subpartcode,
      PBOM.description as N'DescriptionSubpart',
      PBOO.qty,
      PBOO.producedqty,
      PBOO.machcycletime,
      PBOO.qty-PBOO.producedqty as N'ToProduce',
      case when(PBOO.qty-PBOO.producedqty)*(1+(convert(decimal(4,2),PBOM.waste)/100))<=0 
           then 0 
           else (PBOO.qty-PBOO.producedqty)*(1+(convert(decimal(4,2),PBOM.waste)/100)) 
           end as N'AmountSubpartNeeded',
      (DATEDIFF(dd, PBOO.startdate, PBOO.enddate) + 1)
              -(DATEDIFF(wk, PBOO.startdate, PBOO.enddate) * 2)
              -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, PBOO.startdate) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
              -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, PBOO.enddate) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
              As NoOfWeekDays,
      case when PBOO.machcycletime *((PBOO.qty-PBOO.producedqty)/PBOO.qty)/3600<=0 
           then 0 
           else  Round(PBOO.machcycletime *((PBOO.qty-PBOO.producedqty)/PBOO.qty)/3600,2) 
           end as N'HoursRemaining',
      PBOO.startdate as N'Startdate',
      PBOO.enddate as N'Enddate',
      datepart(year,PBOO.startdate) as N'Year',
      datepart(isoww,PBOO.startdate) as N'Week'
From
         dbo.T_ProductionHeader  AS PH,
         dbo.T_ProdBillofMat as PBOM,
         dbo.T_Part as P,
         dbo.T_ProdBillOfOper as PBOO,
         dbo.T_MachGrp as M 
where
             PH.ProdHeaderDossierCode = PBOM.ProdHeaderDossierCode    AND
    PH.ProdHeaderDossierCode = PBOO.ProdHeaderDossierCode AND
    PBOO.MachGrpCode = M.MachGrpCode AND
    M.DeptCode = '0720' and
    PH.ProdStatusCode BETWEEN 30 and 40 AND
    PBOM.LineNr = '10' and
    left(PH.partcode,1) in ('P', 'H')and
    PBOO.finishedInd = 0
)

Select c.*
,ca.RunningDates, 
c.toproduce/c.NoOfWeekDays as N'ProductionPerWorkDay',
c.amountsubpartneeded/c.NoOfWeekDays as N'AmountSubPartNeededPerWorkDay',
c.HoursRemaining/c.NoOfWeekDays as N'HoursRemainingPerWorkDay'
from
CTE C
cross apply(select cd.yeardate as RunningDates from dbo.T_DayOfYear CD where cd.yeardate>=c.Startdate and cd.yeardate<=c.enddate)ca
```

---

final working code thanks to KumarHarsch.

```
    with CTE As
(
Select PH.ProdHeaderOrdNr,
      PH.ProdstatusCode,
      PH.partcode,
      PH.description as N'Omschrijving',
      PBOM.subpartcode,
      left(p.partgrpcode,1)as N'artikelgroeptype',
      PBOM.description as N'Draad',
      PBOO.qty,
      PBOO.producedqty,
      PBOO.machcycletime,
      PBOO.MachGrpCode,
      pbom.waste,
      PBOO.qty-PBOO.producedqty as N'ToProduce',

      (DATEDIFF(dd, PBOO.startdate, PBOO.enddate) + 1)
              -(DATEDIFF(wk, PBOO.startdate, PBOO.enddate) * 2)
              -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, PBOO.startdate) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
              -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, PBOO.enddate) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
              As NoOfWeekDays,
      PBOO.startdate as N'Startdate',
      PBOO.enddate as N'Enddate'
From
         ((dbo.T_ProductionHeader  AS PH
         inner join  dbo.T_ProdBillofMat as PBOM on  PH.ProdHeaderDossierCode = PBOM.ProdHeaderDossierCode)
         inner join dbo.T_ProdBillOfOper as PBOO on PH.ProdHeaderDossierCode = PBOO.ProdHeaderDossierCode),
         dbo.T_MachGrp as M,
         dbo.T_part as P  
where

    PBOO.MachGrpCode = M.MachGrpCode AND
    M.DeptCode = '0720' and
    PH.ProdStatusCode in ( 11, 30, 40 ) AND
    PBOM.LineNr = '10' and
    left(PH.partcode,1) in ('P', 'H')and
    PBOO.finishedInd = 0 and
    p.partcode = pbom.subpartcode

    )

Select c.*
,ca.RunningDates,
cf.ndagen,
      datepart(year,ca.RunningDates) as N'Year_Run',
      datepart(isoww,ca.RunningDates) as N'Week_Run',
case when c.producedqty>convert(decimal(6,2),((DATEDIFF(dd, c.startdate, ca.RunningDates) + 1)
              -(DATEDIFF(wk, c.startdate, ca.RunningDates) * 2))) * (c.qty/cf.ndagen) then 0
              else (((DATEDIFF(dd, c.startdate, ca.RunningDates) + 1)
              -(DATEDIFF(wk, c.startdate, ca.RunningDates) * 2)) * (c.qty/cf.ndagen))  - (((DATEDIFF(dd, c.startdate, ca.RunningDates) + 1)
              -(DATEDIFF(wk, c.startdate, ca.RunningDates) * 2)-1) * (c.qty/cf.ndagen)) - (case when c.producedqty>((DATEDIFF(dd, c.startdate, ca.RunningDates) + 1)
              -(DATEDIFF(wk, c.startdate, ca.RunningDates) * 2)-1) * (c.qty/cf.ndagen) then (c.producedqty-(((DATEDIFF(dd, c.startdate, ca.RunningDates) + 1)
              -(DATEDIFF(wk, c.startdate, ca.RunningDates) * 2)-1) * (c.qty/cf.ndagen))) else 0 end) end
              As ProductionPerWorkDay,
 case when c.producedqty>convert(decimal(6,2),((DATEDIFF(dd, c.startdate, ca.RunningDates) + 1)
              -(DATEDIFF(wk, c.startdate, ca.RunningDates) * 2))) * (c.qty/cf.ndagen) then 0
              else (((DATEDIFF(dd, c.startdate, ca.RunningDates) + 1)
              -(DATEDIFF(wk, c.startdate, ca.RunningDates) * 2)) * (c.qty/cf.ndagen))  - (((DATEDIFF(dd, c.startdate, ca.RunningDates) + 1)
              -(DATEDIFF(wk, c.startdate, ca.RunningDates) * 2)-1) * (c.qty/cf.ndagen)) - (case when c.producedqty>((DATEDIFF(dd, c.startdate, ca.RunningDates) + 1)
              -(DATEDIFF(wk, c.startdate, ca.RunningDates) * 2)-1) * (c.qty/cf.ndagen) then (c.producedqty-(((DATEDIFF(dd, c.startdate, ca.RunningDates) + 1)
              -(DATEDIFF(wk, c.startdate, ca.RunningDates) * 2)-1) * (c.qty/cf.ndagen))) else 0 end) end *(1+(convert(decimal(4,2),c.waste)/100)) 
              as subpartneededperworkday,
      case when c.machcycletime *((case when c.producedqty>convert(decimal(6,2),((DATEDIFF(dd, c.startdate, ca.RunningDates) + 1)
              -(DATEDIFF(wk, c.startdate, ca.RunningDates) * 2))) * (c.qty/cf.ndagen) then 0
              else (((DATEDIFF(dd, c.startdate, ca.RunningDates) + 1)
              -(DATEDIFF(wk, c.startdate, ca.RunningDates) * 2)) * (c.qty/cf.ndagen))  - (((DATEDIFF(dd, c.startdate, ca.RunningDates) + 1)
              -(DATEDIFF(wk, c.startdate, ca.RunningDates) * 2)-1) * (c.qty/cf.ndagen)) - (case when c.producedqty>((DATEDIFF(dd, c.startdate, ca.RunningDates) + 1)
              -(DATEDIFF(wk, c.startdate, ca.RunningDates) * 2)-1) * (c.qty/cf.ndagen) then (c.producedqty-(((DATEDIFF(dd, c.startdate, ca.RunningDates) + 1)
              -(DATEDIFF(wk, c.startdate, ca.RunningDates) * 2)-1) * (c.qty/cf.ndagen))) else 0 end) end)/c.qty)/3600<=0 
           then 0 
           else  Round(c.machcycletime *((case when c.producedqty>convert(decimal(6,2),((DATEDIFF(dd, c.startdate, ca.RunningDates) + 1)
              -(DATEDIFF(wk, c.startdate, ca.RunningDates) * 2))) * (c.qty/cf.ndagen) then 0
              else (((DATEDIFF(dd, c.startdate, ca.RunningDates) + 1)
              -(DATEDIFF(wk, c.startdate, ca.RunningDates) * 2)) * (c.qty/cf.ndagen))  - (((DATEDIFF(dd, c.startdate, ca.RunningDates) + 1)
              -(DATEDIFF(wk, c.startdate, ca.RunningDates) * 2)-1) * (c.qty/cf.ndagen)) - (case when c.producedqty>((DATEDIFF(dd, c.startdate, ca.RunningDates) + 1)
              -(DATEDIFF(wk, c.startdate, ca.RunningDates) * 2)-1) * (c.qty/cf.ndagen) then (c.producedqty-(((DATEDIFF(dd, c.startdate, ca.RunningDates) + 1)
              -(DATEDIFF(wk, c.startdate, ca.RunningDates) * 2)-1) * (c.qty/cf.ndagen))) else 0 end) end)/c.qty)/3600,2) 
           end as N'HoursRemaining'           


from
CTE C
cross apply(select cd.capacityavailabledate as RunningDates from dbo.T_machgrpRealCapacity CD where cd.MachGrpCode = c.MachGrpCode and cd.capacityavailabledate>=c.Startdate and cd.capacityavailabledate<=c.enddate and DATENAME(dw, cd.capacityavailabledate) <> 'Sunday' and DATENAME(dw, cd.capacityavailabledate) <> 'Saturday' )ca
cross apply(select count(*) as ndagen from dbo.T_machgrpRealCapacity CD where cd.MachGrpCode = c.MachGrpCode and cd.capacityavailabledate>=c.Startdate and cd.capacityavailabledate<=c.enddate and DATENAME(dw, cd.capacityavailabledate) <> 'Sunday' and DATENAME(dw, cd.capacityavailabledate) <> 'Saturday' )cf
```

Comment: I'm using Microsoft SQL server 2014. (added to tags)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Create Calendar Table.

Populate in whatever way you want.

```
create table CalendarDate(Dates DateTime primary key)
insert into CalendarDate WITH (TABLOCK)  (Dates)
select top (1000000) 
DATEADD(day, ROW_NUMBER()over(order by (select null))-1,'1970-01-01') DT
from sys.objects
```

Assuming your main query is inside CTE(This script is not tested)

```
With CTE As
(
 Select ,
DATEDIFF(dd, PBOO.startdate, PBOO.enddate) + 1 as Diff
From 
)

Select c.*
,ca.RunningDates 
'to produce'/Datediff
'amount subpart needed'/Datediff
from
CTE C
cross apply(select Dates as RunningDates from CalendarDate CD where cd.dates>=c.Startdate and cd.dates<=c.enddate)ca
```

This answer one important part.if this is correct then you can proceed further.

I hope my change are very clear.

Alias like 'to produce' are wrong it should be one word ToProduce.

**Edit 1,**

```
create table #temp (startdt datetime,enddate datetime)
insert into #temp values('2010-01-01','2010-01-05')
,('2011-02-01','2011-02-06')

select t.*,ca.RunningDate from #temp t
cross apply(select cd.Dates as RunningDate 
from CalendarDate cd 
where cd.Dates>=t.startdt and cd.Dates<=t.enddate)ca

select t.*,cd.Dates as RunningDate from #temp t
inner join  CalendarDate cd 
on cd.Dates>=t.startdt and cd.Dates<=t.enddate

drop table #temp
```

Check your self, it is working fine as intended.

> Cross apply however results in only the first row being showed
>   endlesly with the same value for runningdate

It is not because of CROSS APPLY.Reason must be some thing else.Debug and find it. you.Once comment CROSS APPLY part and check the result or verify the value Calendar Table.

> dbo.T_ProductionHeader  AS PH, dbo.T_ProdBillofMat as PBOM,

Bad practice. Explicitly mention JOIN syntax. Less risk on accidental Cartesian product joins. Comma joins are so last century.It also make easy to understand for others.

```
dbo.T_ProductionHeader  AS PH inner join
 dbo.T_ProdBillofMat as PBOM on PH.ProdHeaderDossierCode = PBOM.ProdHeaderDossierCode    AND
    PH.ProdHeaderDossierCode = PBOO.ProdHeaderDossierCode AND
```

Put the extra filter on where clause like,`PH.ProdStatusCode BETWEEN 30 and 40`.

Comment: Hello KumarHarsch, Thank you for your reply. i allready have a calandertable all date values are datetime2. I changed the aliasses to be one word. the calculation `46.216` is the `231.08 / 5` --> there can be more than 24 hours it just meens more machines. i got the calculations working. Cross apply however results in only the first row being showed endlesly with the same value for runningdate which is equal to the startdate. i'll show my current code and result in the question above